# Purpose of camera in Xcode Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, camera

What's the purpose of this Camera app in Simulator?
[image]

Comment: Probably just there to emulate the real interface as closely as possible?

Answer (score 2):

That button is just there to open a preview of the camera, nothing more. To test the camera you need a real device. That button has been removed in iOS 10 simulator targets.